# Build aliases for a Python porject installed via pip

Tags: pip, alias, python-poetry

What is the simplest way to make an alias for `python -m myproject` when the user installs the package `myproject` via `pip`?

Can `poetry` manages that?

Remainder: `python -m myproject` launches `myproject/__main__.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. With *Poetry*, it is solved by its [`scripts` feature](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts) in the `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.poetry.scripts]
my-command = "myproject.__main__:my_main"
```

where `my_main` is a function in `myproject/__main__.py`:

```py
def my_main():
    # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_main()
```

From then on, you can `poetry install` again and then the `my-command` executable is available. Later, when one "*pip*-installs" your project, they also have the `my-command` executable available.